# Identifying and labelling partial-duplicate records in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame with thousands (~12k) records, and multiple (36) variables. To provide some context, these are observation of animal behaviour. Twenty of the variables record the presence or absence of particular individuals (as Factors with 2 levels).

What I want to achieve is the creation of an additional variable that labels each unique combination of the presence/absence variables. So, if I have the following simplified dataset, where X & Y record variables of interest (details are not relevant to the question) and three individuals A, B, C (where "ab" = absent and "pr" = present):

```
Date      Time    X    Y    A   B   C
17-12-01  10:15   2    4    pr  ab  pr
17-12-01  10:45   3    5    pr  ab  pr
17-12-01  11:15   2    4    ab  pr  pr
17-12-01  11:40   2    4    ab  pr  pr
17-12-01  11:15   6    7    ab  pr  ab
...
```

The possible unique combinations would be:

```
A    B    C
pr   pr   pr
pr   ab   ab
ab   pr   ab
ab   ab   pr
pr   pr   ab
ab   pr   pr
pr   ab   pr
```

[edit: the combination of all 'ab' is - in principle - possible, but would not appear as all individuals would be absent - and thus no observation could be made]

[edit:] desired output:

```
Date      Time    X    Y    A   B   C     Combination
17-12-01  10:15   2    4    pr  ab  pr    1
17-12-01  10:45   3    5    pr  ab  pr    1
17-12-01  11:15   2    4    ab  pr  pr    2
17-12-01  11:40   2    4    ab  pr  pr    2
...                         ab  ab  pr    3    etc.
```

I have found that I can create a new data frame selecting the unique combinations using `distinct` from `dplyr`:

```
newDF = distinct(oldDF, A, B, C, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

but this deletes (or rather fails to include in `newDF`) the duplicates, whereas what I'd like to do is to keep all duplicates but just label each unique combination (all other posts and advice I can find are concerned with deleting duplicates), and the real data frame has 20 'individual' variables, not just three.

So my questions is: *is there a way to use the output from* `distinct` *to achieve this, or have I led myself down a blind alley and another approach is needed*?

Any help much appreciated.

Nick

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Is combination `ab, ab, ab` the only one which does not exist?

Comment: Question edited to provide expected/desired output - unique value for each combination in additional variable - and to explain why ab,ab,ab would not exist in the real data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP has requested to create an additional variable that labels each unique combination of the presence/absence variables. He has supplied a sample dataset with three different variables and a table of possible combinations of the values of the three variables.

To have distinct numbers for the *2<sup>3</sup> - 1* different combinations, we can use:

```
dt[, Combination := .GRP, by = .(A, B, C)][]
```

which numbers the combinations in order of appearance ( `.GRP` is a special symbol in `data.table` syntax):

> ```
>        Date  Time X Y  A  B  C Combination
> 1: 17-12-01 10:15 2 4 pr ab pr           1
> 2: 17-12-01 10:45 3 5 pr ab pr           1
> 3: 17-12-01 11:15 2 4 ab pr pr           2
> 4: 17-12-01 11:40 2 4 ab pr pr           2
> 5: 17-12-01 11:15 6 7 ab pr ab           3
> 6: 17-12-01 11:45 3 4 pr ab pr           1
> ```

Note that the sample dataset provided by the OP has been modified to contain a 6th row which has the same `Combination` number as rows 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks for this informative post. Deleting my answer as I agree it doesn't solve OP's problem, +1. **Edit:** Doh, just realized you can't delete answers that have been marked as answered. Will update it then.

Comment: Have now accepted this answer (not sure of the protocol here; whether I should continue to have accepted the previous answer now updated; or whether it matters?)

Comment: Thanks, @Nick. If my solution gives the correct answer to your problem then this is the correct way. @tyluRp has edited his answer only to point out that his `rleid()` approach was wrong but was not able to delete as long as you had accepted his answer. (BTW, very nice gesture by tyluRp).

Comment: I think `rowid` is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

One approach with `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(id = group_indices(., A, B, C))

      Date  Time X Y  A  B  C id
1 17-12-01 10:15 2 4 pr ab pr  3
2 17-12-01 10:45 3 5 pr ab pr  3
3 17-12-01 11:15 2 4 ab pr pr  2
4 17-12-01 11:40 2 4 ab pr pr  2
5 17-12-01 11:15 6 7 ab pr ab  1
6 17-12-01 11:45 3 4 pr ab pr  3
```

Comment: Have edited the question to show that I would need the 'id' variable to hold a different value for each unique combination (sorry for not being clearer).

Comment: Yes, `group_indices()` works but I noticed the values in `Combination` are slightly different (though it still correctly adds unique id's for each group). I'll post the results of that one as well.

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer to point to mine. That's very fair. However, instead of deleting (as you has suggested) I suggest that just remove the wrong `rleid()` stuff and leave the `group_indices()` approach as alternative to my (now accepted) solution.

Comment: Updated. Thanks again for the valuable information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relatively simple extension of your own approach using dplyr:

```
tab %>%
  left_join(distinct(tab, A, B, C, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
              mutate(unique = "1"), suffix = c(".x", ".y"))
```

you merge the full and distinct data frames labeling the distinct one with a unique label

```
#output:
      Date  Time X Y  A  B  C unique
1 17-12-01 10:15 2 4 pr ab pr      1
2 17-12-01 10:45 3 5 pr ab pr   <NA>
3 17-12-01 11:15 2 4 ab pr pr      1
4 17-12-01 11:40 2 4 ab pr pr   <NA>
5 17-12-01 11:15 6 7 ab pr ab      1
```

One can additional code to replace NAs

```
.... %>%
replace_na(list(unique = 0))
```

where tab is:

```
tab = read.table(text = "Date      Time    X    Y    A   B   C
17-12-01  10:15   2    4    pr  ab  pr
17-12-01  10:45   3    5    pr  ab  pr
17-12-01  11:15   2    4    ab  pr  pr
17-12-01  11:40   2    4    ab  pr  pr
17-12-01  11:15   6    7    ab  pr  ab", header = T)
```

Here is a performance measure:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(tab %>%
                 left_join(distinct(tab, A, B, C, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
                             mutate(unique = "1"), suffix = c(".x", ".y")) %>%
                 replace_na(list(unique = 0)),
tab %>%
  group_by(A, B, C) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number(),
         label = case_when(id >= 2 ~ "duplicate",
                           TRUE ~ "unique")))

#output with 100000 rows: `tab <- tab[sample(1:5, 100000, replace = T),]`

     min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 12.099989 12.564350 13.43444 12.88050 13.44687 34.73189   100
  9.374461  9.928966 11.62848 10.33991 11.57404 49.86249   100

#output with 1 million rows:

      min       lq     mean   median        uq      max neval
 83.26594 85.65350 94.57422 86.24378 105.48224 254.9932   100
 68.81993 88.88253 92.75600 91.22021  93.06835 255.9896   100
```

so similar  performance

Comment: @Uwe I added comparison using 100k and 1 million  rows. The initial test was just done on 5 rows and a much slower PC. However this is not the requested output.